# record with micro phone in intervals iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am implementing recording functionality in intervals in background. I have used micro phone and Audio Capabilities to record audio which make app running in background continuously.

My requirement is to record in back ground for intervals i.e i will record for 10 mins and 50 mins i will not record and custom intervals will  be given where app need to record in that intervals.

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];` is used for recording.

How i can achieve recording in intervals in background?.

Answer (score 1):

You would need something lower level, e.g. Core-Audio, and use the intervals to control when to write the audio buffer to the file. Checkout [Extended Audio File Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/index.html)

Im not sure on the battery usage but you would essentially just be ignoring the audio buffer if the current time was not inside your recording timeframe, if it is, then you pass the buffer to the asynchronous write to file operation [ExtAudioFileWriteAsync](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ExtAudioFileWriteAsync)

You would need to open the file beforehand and close it after the session is done, possibly through a user controlled interaction when the app is in the foreground.